# Unable to get display on monitor from Android Things preview 5.0

Tags: android-things

Earlier I had Android Things preview 3 in my raspberry PI3 device. On connecting it with an HDMI cable, start up screen was visible on my DELL monitor. Also I can see my application state on the screen (my application was running swiftly on the board).

However after flashing my device with Android Things preview 5.0, I am unable to get the display. Also on running the application I am getting following message:
'*Waiting for application to come online:package-name*'

I have tried to edit the configure.txt file but it does not seems to work.

Comment: there is a new preview 0.5.1 available. It detects display settings automatically. Maybe it will work.

Comment: subham shekhar are you able to find any solution for that

Comment: @simply-put No, I did not find any possible solution for the problem. My code is running but I am unable to see any output in my monitor.